# How to add detailed data to rows?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I use gijgo from gijgo.com/Grid for a `datatable` control. so far for standard data loading it works like charm and was super fast. But now i need to add **sub-grids** aka **grid in a row**. as show on this image:

[image]

The Gijgo website has some sample codes on generating the regular datatables but not much information of generating sub-grids.

I have the following code written to generate the primary table

```html
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="grid" style="margin-left:5%;">
  @*<thead>
  <tr>
    <th width="100em" data-field="ProductID">Product ID</th>
    <th data-field="Name">Name</th>
    <th data-field="ProductNumber" data-min-width="250" data-priority="1">Product Number</th>            
  </tr>
  </thead>*@
</table>

@section Scripts{
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/grid.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var grid = $('#grid').grid({
        columns: [
          { title: 'CategoryID', field: 'Category ID' },
          { title: 'Name', field: 'Name' },
          { title: 'Is Blocked', field: 'Blocked' }
        ],
        dataSource: 'Home/GetData',
        uiLibrary:'bootstrap',
        detailTemplate: '<div class="divT row"><table class="tbl" data-source="Home/GetAllProducts"></table></div>',/*****/
        responsive: true,
        showHiddenColumnsAsDetails: false,
        width: 800,

      });
    })
}
```

i have used property "detailTemplate" to create a detail section as mentioned on  [Gijgo demo site](http://gijgo.com/Grid/Demos/ResponsiveDesign2). it does not generate the inner table in each row. The data for the inner table comes from DB.

The above code supposed to list all categories as the primary rows and under each row it should display all products for that category in an inner grid.

Is there away to accomplish my task of sub-grids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that would be best if you use the detailExpand event to load data in a subgrids.
You can read more about this event at http://gijgo.com/Grid/Events/detailExpand

Here is the example:

```
   var grid, data = [ {ID: 1, Name: 'test 1'}, {ID: 2, Name: 'test 2'}, {ID: 3, Name: 'test 3'} ];
   grid = $('#grid').grid({
         dataSource: '/version_0_6/Grid/GetPlayers',
         detailTemplate: '<div></div>',
         columns: [ { field: 'ID' }, { field: 'Name' }, { field: 'DateOfBirth', type: 'date' } ]
     });
   grid.on('detailExpand', function (e, $detailWrapper, record) {
         var subggrid = $detailWrapper.append('<table id="subgrid"/>').find('table').grid({
           dataSource: data,
           columns: [{ field: 'ID', width: 20 }, { field: 'Name' }],
           pager: { limit: 2 }
         });
         subggrid.on('pageChanging', function (e, newPage) {
             e.stopPropagation();
           });
     });
     grid.on('detailCollapse', function (e, $detailWrapper, record) {
         $detailWrapper.empty();
     });
```

Comment: After changing subgrid data the newly changed data is not updated When I call `grid.getAll();` . Any suggestions?